# Can't Upload Project to iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode5

Hi I am trying to upload my first app to iTunes Connect. I have my details on iTunes Connect setup but I am facing problems uploading my archives. Here is the screenshot of errors I face

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error sounds like you're trying to upload an app either with a version of Xcode lower than 5.1.1 or Xcode 6 Beta. Neither is possible at the time of writing (August 2014).

You currently need to upload apps with Xcode 5.1.1, with a maximum deployment target of iOS 7.1 or OS X 10.9.

Comment: Hi I am using Xcode 5.1 and I don't see an update in the App Store. My target is iOS 7.

Comment: Target is fine, but you need to use Xcode 5.1.1. If you don't see it under Apple Icon - Software Updates, head over to developer.apple.com and download Xcode 5.1.1 from there.